# Calendar recurrent rule - Consecutive days: Every First and third Friday and Saturday

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar, rrule

In Google Calendar, using `rrule`, I want to make recurrent events for two **consecutive days**:

- Friday and Saturday
- Twice a month with 2 weeks apart

What I would expect to match my requirement is any of the 2 options below:

| Possible option | 1st match | 2nd match |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | fri 30 - sat 1 | fri 14 - sat 15 |
| 2 | fri 7 - sat 8 | fri 21 - sat 22 |

The below config shows what I have tried and the screenshot shows the outcome which is certainly not what I want.

The tricky part I believe is when the two days belong to 2 different moths. Luckily I noticed this since it was the case this May.

Any idea how to solve this?

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0

BEGIN:VEVENT
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=FR;BYSETPOS=1
SUMMARY:EventDay1
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20210501
SEQUENCE:0
DESCRIPTION:EventDay1
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=FR;BYSETPOS=3
SUMMARY:EventDay1
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20210501
SEQUENCE:0
DESCRIPTION:EventDay1
END:VEVENT

BEGIN:VEVENT
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=SA;BYSETPOS=1
SUMMARY:EventDay2
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20210501
SEQUENCE:0
DESCRIPTION:EventDay2
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=SA;BYSETPOS=3
SUMMARY:EventDay2
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20210501
SEQUENCE:0
DESCRIPTION:EventDay2
END:VEVENT

END:VCALENDAR
```

[image]

Comment: It should somehow check whether Friday is the last day of a month, and correct the different `BYSETPOS` if that was the case. I don't think there's a rule that can accomplish that. I guess making a single event that includes both days (Friday and Saturday) would not be desired?

Comment: Yes, I though about a 2 days event indeed as solution, but I was wondering If I was missing something. I just looked around and couldn't see how to make such rule, can you suggest something please ?

Comment: Hi! I posted an answer, could you please confirm if that solution works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `BYMONTHDAY` instead of `BYSETPOS` to specify the first and third weeks of the month:

- 1st Friday: `BYMONTHDAY=1,2,3,4,5,6,7`
- 1st Saturday: `BYMONTHDAY=2,3,4,5,6,7,8`
- 3rd Friday: `BYMONTHDAY=15,16,17,18,19,20,21`
- 3rd Saturday: `BYMONTHDAY=16,17,18,19,20,21,22`

Arguably less elegant than `BYSETPOS`, but it solves the issue:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0

BEGIN:VEVENT
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=FR;BYMONTHDAY=1,2,3,4,5,6,7
SUMMARY:EventDay1
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20210430
EXDATE;VALUE=DATE:20210430
SEQUENCE:0
DESCRIPTION:EventDay1
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=FR;BYMONTHDAY=15,16,17,18,19,20,21
SUMMARY:EventDay1
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20210430
EXDATE;VALUE=DATE:20210430
SEQUENCE:0
DESCRIPTION:EventDay1
END:VEVENT

BEGIN:VEVENT
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=SA;BYMONTHDAY=2,3,4,5,6,7,8
SUMMARY:EventDay2
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20210430
EXDATE;VALUE=DATE:20210430
SEQUENCE:0
DESCRIPTION:EventDay2
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=SA;BYMONTHDAY=16,17,18,19,20,21,22
SUMMARY:EventDay2
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20210430
EXDATE;VALUE=DATE:20210430
SEQUENCE:0
DESCRIPTION:EventDay2
END:VEVENT

END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Brilliant. It indeed answers the question. I have indeed saw `BYMONTHDAY` can force the admissible interval for the expected days but I didn't look further as it seemed less elegant. I continued on another path until I hit a wall and totally forgot about the other option... At this level, I regret taking the wrong path xD